# Flask / Gcloud error "content must be served over HTTPS"

Tags: python, flask, gcloud

I have a Flask app running on Gcloud that uses an html web page to send images to a Python script for predictions (drawing from a model saved in the root directory).

When I send predictions I get the error "content must be served over HTTPS".

How do I configure flask to exclusively use HTTPS? My html is already using:

```
    $.post("https://0.0.0.0:5000/predict", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){
```

Do I need to change something in the Python as well?

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide an SSL certificate to run the Flask app using HTTPs

```py
from flask import Flask
from OpenSSL import SSL

context = SSL.Context(SSL.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.use_privatekey_file('server.key')
context.use_certificate_file('server.crt')   

app = Flask(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000, ssl_context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to solve the issue - The full error is : "jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://architectural-style-classifier.uc.r.appspot.com/predict' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/predict'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS. " Is the issue coming from the html or the python?

Comment: If you are now not configuring SSL on the python side, then you need to call API with HTTP not HTTPS.

Comment: Do I have to use the flexible runtime environment for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, your website is being served over HTTPS but within your application code (your html page, your raw codes, etc) you have references to links which use HTTP. You'll have to make sure every link embedded in your site or being called uses HTTPS. This includes links to images, javascript files (like a link to your JQUERY file), CSS files, etc.

Example

a) You are linking to a jquery CDNS as `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js.`
You have to change it to - `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Also you're probably getting this error because you have set your site to always use HTTPS (I see you're using Google App Engine; You most likely set your app.yaml to use 'secure' always routing). The other option (not really advisable since it is always good to use https) is to turn off 'secure' always in your app.yaml file.

Comment: Looking at your post again, it seems to me like you are making a call to your dev server (0.0.0.:5000) from your production server. It is usually quite difficult to configure https on your local server and so if you must make this kind of calls, consider using 'ngrok.io' which will allow you to get an 'https' connection that routes to your local server

Comment: OK so could I just change the IP it's calling too? For example ```$.post("https://127.0.0.1:8080/predict/", JSON.stringify(message), function(response){``` (in html) and ```if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=8080, ssl_context=context) ``` (in python) I also wasn't using the flexible environment in my yaml file initially, not sure if that's something I have to use instead - when I use flexible it becomes much much slower (this script uses tensorflow so maybe that's related)

Comment: Unless you have configured 'https' on your local server, you can't do ```https://127.0.0.1```. 
Instead install [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.com/) which will give you something like ```https://123456789.ngrok.io:8080/predict/``` which has been mapped to your dev server